# CSRF Requesting the nonce makes malicious POST possible?

Tags: security, csrf

I am trying to wrap my head around csrf protection and there is something I have trouble understanding. Maybe someone can give me the insight I need :).

**What I understand**

Say we have no csrf protection. Someone logs in to a website A with his/her credentials. After valid login a session cookie is stored in the browser. The user POSTS some data through a form and the sever accepts it with no trouble. Since we have no csrf protection this opens the system up for a vulnerability.

The user visits another website B, a malicious website like a phishing attempt. This website is posting to website A in the background with some javascript xhr request for example. The browser has the cookie stored for website A and since the user was logged in already this is a valid session. Therefore website A will accept the post without any trouble.

To solve this csrf protection comes in. Upon loading the page with the form on website A from the server a nonce (one time code) is generated. This code must be submitted with the form so the server can check if this post came from the same session that requested the form. If the code is the same as the one that was just generated the form is accepted. If the code is missing or incorrect, the server says no.

**Question**

If malicious website B first makes a get request to the page that renders the form. It would be able to fetch the token to send along with the post request afterwards. Right? Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you concern is that a malicious website can request your anti-CSRF token.

You would need to prevent cross-origin reads or embedding of pages or endpoints that returns the CSRF tokens. One of the important things to keep in mind is that CORS don't provide CSRF protection, as preflight CORS requests are not always executed by the browser, for example when using regular html forms.

Most modern browsers block cross origin requests by default. When you do need cross origin requests for your own domains, can you do that by setting the correct Cross Origin headers, like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: sub.domain.com`.
To prevent embedding in an `iframe` you can implement the `X-Frame-Options:` to  `DENY`, or `SAMEORIGIN`.

You can find more information on https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy